# Queuing/throttling jQuery ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I need to fire a number of ajax requests at a server and then run a callback when they are finished.  Normally this would be easy using jQuery's `deferred.done()` .  However to avoid overwhelming the server, I'm queuing the requests, and firing one every X milliseconds.

e.g

```
var promisesList = [];

var addToQueue = function(workflow) {
    workflowQueue.push(workflow);
  }

var startWorkflow = function(workflow) {
    return $.ajax($endointURL, {
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        action: workflow.id
      },
      success: function() {
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      }
    });
  };

  var startWorkflows = function() {
    var promisesList = [];
    if (workflowQueue.length > 0) {
      var workflow = workflowQueue.shift();
      promisesList.push(startWorkflow(workflow));
      setTimeout(startWorkflows, delay);
    }
  };

startWorkflows();
$.when(promisesList).done(function(){
  //do stuff
});
```

The problem with this is, that the `promisesList` array is initially empty, so the `done()` callback fires immediately, and **then** the ajax requests start getting sent by the `setTimeout()`.  Is there an easy way to create the ajax requests initially and kind of "pause" them, then fire them using `setTimeout()`.

I've found various throttle/queue implementations to fire ajax requests sequentially, but I'm happy for them to be fired in parallel, just with a delay on them.

Comment: `setTimeout` with arbitrary delay not an option?

Comment: I'm using `setTimout()`, the problem is handling the `deferred` objects.

Comment: I am guessing that you need to handle the $.when part per request ... or that you wait til all are sent and then do when ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing you're stumbling upon is that `when()` doesn't work this way with arrays. It accepts an arbitrary list of promises so you can get around that by applying an array using:

```
$.when.apply(null, promiseList).done(function(){
    // Do something
    // use the `arguments` magic property to get an ordered list of results
});
```

Secondly, the throttling method can be done with $.ajax param of {delay:timeInSeconds} but I've proposed a solution that sets up a new defered which is immediately returned (to keep the order) but resolved after a timeout.

See http://jsfiddle.net/9Acb2/1/ for an interactive example

Comment: (a) I was sure that `$.when()` worked like that!  Checked and you're correct it doesn't accept arrays.  Odd, seems the obvious thing for it to do.
(b) I can't see a `delay` param in the jQ docs for ajax requests?
(c) Your fiddle is perfect, I hadn't thought of manually creating the `$.Deferreds()` like that.   Many thanks!